# Keep Notifications when turn on the smartphone

Tags: android, android-studio, notifications

I have this application to create notifications but I need to keep them when the smartphone turn on/restart. I tried to create a service and auto-start the app when the smartphone turn on but is useless. What can I do?

this is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button guardar, cancelar;
EditText nota;
ListView lista;
ArrayList<String> notas;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador;
NotificationManager notificationManager;
SharedPreferences preferencias;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
int cpos; //cantidad de posiciones ya guardadas
Intent intent;
PendingIntent pIntent;
Notification n;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
    notas = new ArrayList<String>();
    adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notas);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);

    preferencias = getSharedPreferences("notas", 0);
    editor = getSharedPreferences("notas", 0).edit();

    cpos = preferencias.getInt("posicionesT", -1);

    for(int i = 0; i <= cpos; i++)
    {
        notas.add(preferencias.getString(Integer.toString(i), ""));
        adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.add)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nota, null);

        guardar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.guardar);
        cancelar = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelar);
        nota = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.nota);

        cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                notas.add(nota.getText().toString());
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();

                cpos++;
                editor.putInt("posicionesT", cpos);
                editor.putString(Integer.toString(cpos), nota.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();

                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

                n  = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setContentTitle("Recordar")
                        .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(nota.getText()))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icono)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                        .setColor(Color.parseColor("#4CAF50"))
                        .setOngoing(true) //notificacion persistente
                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_borrar, "Quitar nota", pIntent).build();


                notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(cpos, n);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alerta.setView(dialog);
        alerta.show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notifications don't last around restart.  TO make what you want happen you need to

1)Write the notifications to disk in some matter (shared preferences,database, file, whatever) when you get one

2)Remove them when the notification is canceled, so you don't redisplay on accident.

3)Write a BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast receiver.  Have it read the stored notifications and create new ones with the same info

Comment: are you saing that add android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"> only or create a service to read the list of notifications saved to restore?

Comment: You need to add the permission and create a BroadcastReceiver to receive the broadcast, and register that receiver in the manifest.  You can choose to have the receiver start a service, but I don't think that's strictly necessary-  you can do the processing directly in the receiver.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: I created the broadcastreceiver but I can't create notifications because I can't do getApplicationContext()

Comment: A context is passed into the onReceive function.  Use that, or call getApplicationContext on that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm so stupid haha...the last question and I leave you alone: in notificationManager I can't do getSystemService. What can I do?

Comment: Call context.getSystemService